# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, warnings

This is not my entire program here but I think these are the only parts you are going to need as these are the only functions used.

```
typedef struct
{
char name[64];
int balance;
int gain;
}
Player;

Player Players[10];
FILE *fp;

Player GetPlayerData(const char* name, Player p){
  char First[100];
  int i = 0;
  for (;;)
  {
      if (strcmp(name, p[i].name) == 0)
      {
        return p[i];
      }
     /*else{
        printf("The name you inputed is not on the list.\n"
        "Here are the names that are: \n");
        while(1){
          fscanf(fp, "%s", &First);
          printf("\n%s %d", First);
          if(feof(fp) == 1){
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      i++;*/
  }
}

void TopBal(){
  char name[64];
  int Add[100];

  printf("Enter your name: ");
  scanf("%s", &name);
  Player p = GetPlayerData(name, Players);
  printf("How much money would you like to add: ");
  scanf("%d", &Add);
  p.balance = p.balance + Add;
  printf("Your balance is now %d", p.balance);
  //PushPlayerData(FILE_NAME, name);
}
```

This is the warning.
./Project.c: In function ‘TopBal’:
./Project.c:108:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   (p).balance = (p).balance + Add;

Comment: either add should be an integer variable or you should index the array to get the value back from the array.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &name);` is wrong; it passes a `char (*)[64]` to `scanf()` but you told it to expect a `char *`.  Drop the `&`.

Comment: Be aware that this warning is rather an error than a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add` is an array and it is converted to a pointer in expressions (excluding some exceptions like operand of `sizeof` operatpr).

You are not using multi-element feature of the array `Add`, so it should be simple variable `int Add;`, not `int Add[100];`.

You should also remove `&` in `scanf("%s", &name);` because it causes type mismatch (an pointer to array `char(*)[64]` is passed while an pointer to character `char*` is expected), which invokes *undefined behavior*.
Be aware again that most arrays in expressions are converted to pointers.

Comment: also as a sidenote, shouldn't the signature contain Player* p, instead of Player p? cause he is passing an array and receiving a plain variable. That shouldn't even compile right?

Comment: That actually ended up being my solution! I forgot to check back into here as I went back to work on it when my friend pointed out that I had put it as an array and taking it out of an array worked perfectly! I had gotten just so used to putting everything as an Array for this project I just did it without thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
p.balance // This is int
 = p.balance // again int
 + Add; // but this is int array / pointer
```

you probably meant to deference Add. e.g.

```
 p.balance = p.balance + Add[0];
```